# Is there a LEGO clamping tool?

Tags: tools

Sometimes we cannot easily attach 2 LEGO pieces.

Is there a tool to help clamp together LEGO pieces that are very tight?

Answer (score 3):

I agree that sometimes adding smaller plates can be tricky - the issue is usually caused by misalignment of the studs and holes.

You could use one of the Brick Separators in reverse (i.e. add the brick to the separator and then attach it to the other part), or you could try adding a larger brick first temporarily to help you line up the piece.

The other elements that we have trouble with are the hinges and clips, and for that I've found just taking your time and easing it gently is the best option.

Comment: Agreed. Most of the time alignment is the issue, and clamping pieces will just break them.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re using regular bricks and plates, there is really no sure way to tightly lock them together. The only way to ensure secure assembly is to use special or Technic pieces.

If you use special bricks with “knobs” separating each row or layer with two rows or layers of plates, you can then use plates across the knobs.

A more secure assembly would be to use Technic bricks with connector pegs, separate each row with two rows of plates and use Technic beams across the connector pegs.

If you have a wall structure that is two units thick you can also use bearing elements which are 2×2 bricks with snaps.